A surprisingly simple and difficult problem on sums of upper bounds
Let $T$ be a large integer, and $C$ be a positive real constant.
Consider a sequence $\{p_t\}_{T\geq t\geq 1}$ of real numbers in $[0,1]$. The sequence $\{b_t\}_{T\geq t\geq 1}$ can be defined as follows. $b_t$ is the unique value that makes the following equation true, or 1, whichever is less.
$$\sum_{t\geq k\geq 1}\frac{\max(b_{t}-p_{k},0)}{\sqrt{k}}=C$$
I'm trying to show that no matter what the sequence $\{p_t\}$ is, then
$$\mathcal{O}(C\sqrt{T}\text{polylog}(T))\geq\sum_{T\geq t\geq 1}(b_t-p_t)$$
The conjecture will be false if $\max_{\{p_t\}_{T\geq t\geq 1}}\sum_{T\geq t\geq 1}(b_t-p_t)$ scales as $T^{1/2+\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon$.
Some partial progress on this problem: First, we can always assume $p_1\geq p_2\geq...\geq p_{T-1}\geq p_T$. This is because a violation of monotonicity, with $p_t$ followed by a larger $p_{t+1}$, can have $p_t$ and $p_{t+1}$ swapped, which can only increase the sum of $b_t$ values, while keeping the $p_t$ sum constant. So, the sequence of p's which saturates the bound is guaranteed to be a decreasing sequence.
A second piece of progress is that, if a discrete-to-continuous transference result works out (and it seems that it probably will), we can look at the closely related problem, where $p:[1,T]\to[0,1]$ is a continuous, differentiable, downwards-monotone function, and we have that $b:[1,T]\to[0,1]$ is defined to either be 1, or to fulfill the property that $b(t)$ is such that the following equation holds.
$$\int_{k=1}^{k=t}\frac{\max(b(t)-p(k),0)}{\sqrt{k}}dk=C$$
Neglecting the initial segment where $b(t)=1$, from this, we can derive the property
$$b'(t)=\frac{-1}{2}\frac{b(t)-p(t)}{t-\sqrt{t\cdot p^{-1}(b(t))}}$$
All this is just true, but from here on out, we move to a closely related problem where a $\sqrt{T}$ bound can be proven.
Given the function $p$, a new function $f$ could be defined by being 1 where $b$ is 1, and then fulfilling the equation
$$f'(t)=-\frac{f(t)-p(t)}{t-p^{-1}(f(t))}$$
from there on out. This is the same differential equation as that which defines $b$, just with the geometric mean replaced by the arithmetic mean. The quantity in the denominator is lower, so it's more negative, so the function $f$ will always be $\leq b$. As it turns out, via some clever arguments from my coworker, we do have
$$\mathcal{O}(C\sqrt{T})\geq\int_{t=1}^{T}f(t)-p(t)dt$$
holding, which offers some hope for a similar bound holding in the geometric mean case.
